# Écriture inclusive d' « amis parisiens » et du pronom « quelqu'un » : stratégies de rédaction épicène ?

Tags: genre, écriture

I am looking to make an announcement to friends that uses more gender-balanced French. I know that hyphens and parentheses are generally used to separate letters that distinguish genders, but sometimes writing adjectives to properly agree with their corresponding noun can be a bit tricky. Given that this isn't standard French, there are not many resources for how to 'properly' write these types of sentences. I am hoping to crowdsource basic strategies that people use.

For example, in my announcement, I would like to clarify that the message is relevant to my friends in Paris, but 'parisiens --> parisiennes' isn't as simple as just adding an 'es'. My best attempt is:

> Ami-e-s parisien-ne-s : [nom de l'artiste] viendra à Paris en mars prochain. Y a-t-il quelq'un-e qui veut y aller ?

Comment: *Quelq**u**'une* seems overkill.

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed - probably grammaticalized, not separately parsed. Or does a female speaker say "Je suis quelqu'une qui..."?

Comment: @LukeSawczak There are cases where *quelqu'une* is possible but a sentence like *je suis quelqu'une de sérieuse* would startle native French speakers.

Comment: @jlliagre Well, the *de sérieuse* is impossible in any case (cp. « C'est quelque chose de beau »). When can one say *quelqu'une*, though?

Comment: @LukeSawczak *J'en voudrais une de sérieuse* is correct French. Several examples of *quelqu'une* in the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu%27un)

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste Oui. je soupçonne que les votes négatifs sont en fait des votes contre l'écriture inclusive elle-même plutôt que sur la qualité ou l'intérêt de la question.

Answer (score 5):

> Ami·e·s parisiens et parisiennes,

Seems less confusing to me. I'd use the "·" instead of the "-" as it is often recommended.

Same goes for

> quelqu'un·e

But I would personnaly use

> une personne

Finally, on a side note, I'd look into the "veut", I'm not sure if "voudrait" would be better conjugation.

Comment: I agree, except with *"une personne"*: *"Y a-t-il une personne qui veut y aller ?"* sounds weird

Comment: and about "veut", I agree that it must be changed, *"voudrait"* would do but I would go for *"veuille*" (subjonctif)

Comment: For the last question, I would suggest *Est-ce que l'un.e d'entre-vous souhaiterais y aller ?*

Comment: I agree with jiliagre's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

On peut utiliser un nom collectif [*gens*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gens) au pluriel (*les gens de Paris*, précédé d'une interpellation avec [*eh*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/eh) par exemple), avec le sens de la [*personne*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28077) dont on parle ailleurs. On peut reformuler la question avec le pronom relatif *qui*, [non marqué](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3989) en genre (*Qui veut y aller / Qui veut aller voir son spectacle*)?. Différents choix sont possibles tant en ce qui a trait au nom ([nom collectif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3984)) et au pronom (non marqué) qu'au niveau de la formulation de la [phrase](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3987) (épicène). Pour aller plus loin voir cette [bibliographie](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4191) et [ceci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=274)...

---

À mon avis, afin d'avoir le texte le plus fluide qui soit, il se révélera sans doute utile de le concevoir dès le départ en [fonction](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne) des critères choisis plutôt que de tenter d'équilibrer un texte après coup, surtout si le résultat devient lourd et la graphie surchargée. Par ailleurs la tolérance à la surcharge et aux brèches à la fluidité varie. Personnellement je préfère une formulation inclusive au marquage systématique avec des signes comme la parenthèse et le trait d'union, par exemple, mais on dispose de plusieurs outils et l'impact « visuel » diffère selon les choix, jamais trop nombreux, à mon avis.