# Gender: de + adjective

Tags: accord, genre

When I learned that one says things like

> Je voudrais **quelque chose de beau**

the rule that I either was told or generalized (I can't remember which) to account for the masculine adjective was that in this construction with *de*, there is no agreement.

However, in a comment on [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28073/%C3%89criture-inclusive-d-amis-parisiens-et-du-pronom-quelquun-strat%C3%A9gies), when I wrote:

> *de sérieuse* is impossible in any case (cp. « C'est quelque chose de beau »)

jlliagre replied:

> *J'en voudrais une de sérieuse* is correct French.

So what is going on? Did I internalize the rule incorrectly?

- Is *quelque chose* somehow not feminine despite *chose* being feminine?
- Is *quelque chose* feminine, but *quelque chose de* is a fixed genderless/masculine expression?
- Some other explanation I haven't thought of?

Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is *chose* can be either invariable or feminine.

*Quelque chose* as a whole is invariable with *quelque* being a indefinite adjective and *chose* an invariable name, so *beau* is "neutral", i.e. masculine.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose/1)

> **II.− C.− c)** Réalité indéfinie mais qualifiée par une précision subséquente. **Quelque chose de** + adj. inv. *Quelque chose de beau, de bon, de grand, de vrai, de vague, de bleu, de neuf, de nouveau, de fâcheux, de merveilleux. Il y a quelque chose de vrai dans ce que vous dites. Il a quelque chose de bienveillant dans la physionomie* (Delécluze, Journal, 1828, p. 107).

You would have feminine when *quelque* is used as a standard adjective and *chose* as a [feminine substantive](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose/0):

> Je voudrais quelque belle chose.

or even

> Quelque chose errante

Comment: Ah! So my second theory - it's not really the same gender as quelque + chose. I can throw out the whole "de" rule then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Quelque chose* is [masculine](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque_chose) (except in some rare exceptions*). From that, there is not problem.

> Quelque chose de **beau**

- Masculine

> J'en voudrais une de **sérieuse**

- It's feminine, but it doesn't use *quelque chose*. I don't really understand why that confuses you, it's not related to the *quelque chose* problem.

I think if you re-read your question you'll understand ^^

---

Jliagre mentioned cases where "*quelque chose*" is feminine, but I think it adds confusion and it's not exactly on the point. However if you encounter them you'll be confused so we might as well explain them.

I see it like the distinction between "**something**" and "**some thing**". One is a fixed expression that became a word by itself, the other is simply two words that but one behind another look like the first one, but don't exactly have the same meaning.

It's the same with "*quelque chose*", it became something you can't split, expect the words stayed separate. In Jliagre's example:

> Quelque chose errante

"*Quelque*" is a dated word that means "some", but would be replaced with "*un*" or "*une*" nowadays, and "chose" can be replaced by another word without breaking the sentence grammatically:

> Quelque créature errante

But in most cases, "*quelque chose*" acts as a fixed whole and you cannot touch it.

Comment: Merci! This is also very useful. I did get jl's point but if I hadn't then your explanation would have done it. If I could choose two right answers I would.