# Pourquoi dit-on « quelque chose de profond » et non « Quelque chose de profondE » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, accord, genre

Spontanément, j’ai envie de dire « quelque chose de profondø » avec *profond* au masculin alors que *chose* est au féminin. Sans doute ai-je ce réflexe parce que j’ai souvent entendu cette locution prononcée ainsi.

Mais donc, je suis incapable d’expliquer la raison syntaxique pour laquelle *profond* s’accorde au masculin d’autant qu’aucun autre mot au masculin n’est présent dans cette phrase.

Dès lors **pourquoi ici *profond* s’accorde au masculin et non au féminin ?**

Comment: Peut-être il s'agit de l'emploi dudit 'masculin générique'.

Comment: See here: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28219/gender-de-adjective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ici on accorde pas avec « chose » mais avec « quelque chose », qui est masculin quand il a un genre. Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque_chose) donne la nuance suivante :

> Généralement de genre neutre (genre exprimé, en cas de reprise pronominale, **par la forme masculine** du pronom personnel ou du pronom relatif).

On retrouve ça notamment dans l'expression « un petit quelque chose ».

Answer (score 1):

Pas sûr de ma réponse. Je crois qu'il s'agit de l'emploi dudit 'masculin générique'.
Une autre explication pourrait être que l'on accorde avec 'quelque chose' qui est masculin ([pronom indéfini masculin](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quelque_chose/65618)).